# PHP echo tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

**Overview**

I have some data stored in MySql database related to Products. I am trying to retrieve this data and display it on a page using HTML table.
The PHP and MySql has gone well and all the data is retrieved but it is displayed in a very messy manner.

Here is what I have as a layout:

[image]

What I am aiming to achieve is to further divide the results table add more columns rows to make the data more readable

Something like this;

[image]

The code: PHP, MySQL & HTML:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include('connect_mysql.php');


    $product_name = 'product_name';
    $product_qua = 'product_qua';
    $product_price = 'product_price';
    $product_image = 'product_image';
    $product_des = 'product_des';


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");

 echo "<table id='display'>";


while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<tr><td>";
    echo"$rows[$product_name]<br></td>";

    echo"<td><img src=$rows[$product_image] height='200px' width='200px'><br></td>";
    echo"<td>Avalible: $rows[$product_qua]<br></td>";
    echo"<td>Price: $rows[$product_price]<br></td>";
    echo"<td>Description: $rows[$product_des]<br></td>";    
    echo"</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

CSS responsible for this part:

```
#display{
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-left:100px;


}
```

Comment: You need to add borders and probably also padding to your tds [edit: what krike said in his answer]. Aside from that, you have a "<br>" misplaced.

Answer (score 6):

just add some padding or a border to the table cells:

```
table#display td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0 8px;

}
```

Edit: What you could do as well:

```
<table id='display'>
<?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)): ?>
    <!-- <br>  <- why a break? it's not in the correct spot anyway --> 
<tr><td>
<?php echo $rows[$product_name]; ?><br>
</td>
<td> - </td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $rows[$product_image]; ?>" height='200px' width='200px'><br></td>
<td> - </td>
<td>Avalible: <?php echo $rows[$product_qua]; ?><br></td>
<td> - </td>    
<td>Price: <?php echo $rows[$product_price]; ?><br></td>
<td> - </td>
<td>Description: <?php echo $rows[$product_des]; ?><br></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Tip: I prefer to use the while/endwhile; approach rather than using brackets when displaying data to the user.

Comment: one final quick question...say i want to separate each item all together not just by a "line" how could this be achived

Comment: They are already separated. each item is in his own cell. The only separation is now visually. Through a line or you could an extra td between your data and add a separating character. (will update my answer)

Answer (score 5):

First of all don't echo so much HTML using PHP, instead do it like this

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include('connect_mysql.php');

    $product_name = 'product_name';
    $product_qua = 'product_qua';
    $product_price = 'product_price';
    $product_image = 'product_image';
    $product_des = 'product_des';


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products"); ?> 

<table id='display'> 
    <?php 
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    ?>
       <tr><td><?php echo $rows[$product_name]; ?></td>
       <!-- And so on--> 
     <?php   
        } 
     ?> 
 </table>
```

Secondly by seeing your inmage, it seems like you need a border for your table so use

```
table, td {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: ok thx for your advice applied your suggested technique and it seems to work but my question is how does this benefit my code :P hope its not a lame question hehe

Comment: I'd say it makes your code easier to read on a decent text editor.  You can also write even less by simplifying the <?php echo $var; ?> to <?= $var ?>

Answer (score 1):

add the following css to apply border on your table cells:

```
#display td{ border: 2px solid red; }
```

and optionally add to your #display { :

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```